# Clipping part of basemap on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, clip, arcgis-online-basemaps

Can I clip a part of a basemap on ArcMap 10.4?

I'd like to know if it is possible to clip a basemap, specifically OpenStreetMap.

Comment: I am not sure about openstreet maps but arc basemaps can be clipped to a shape, right click on layer, then properties, then data frame, and you can clip to the other featureclass from there.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you mean extracting an image from a basemap raster (flux). You can add your basemap, then go to File/Export Map...

[image]

In the dialog box, set the dpi you need, and for example for JPG files, don't forget to check the "Write World File" box. Then you insert your exported image.

[image]

Next step if you really need to **CLIP** by for example a polygone boundary, is to use the [Extract By Mask](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm) Tool on your new image (you will need Spatial analyst Extension for this last part).